# How to purge local i18n wordpress cache?

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm using valet+ and Wordpress 5.9 on a local environment.

I have a simple task of updating some new terms of my payment module.

They are located under `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages/my-plugin.*` where `*` represents `.pot` and `-pt_BR.mo` and `-pt_BR.po` files.

Some old terms are still working in the admin, even if I remove everything in this folder and refresh the page. The new terms are not being translated at all.

I already tried to restart valet (php, nginx, etc), and also used `wp-cli cache flush` command.

Am I missing something here? Or is there any other place to look for translation cache that I am leaving behind?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that wordpress was loading another file located under `wpcontent/languages/plugin/my-plugin.*`.

Removing those files solved the problem. No cache cleaning or restart was needed on local environment.